# Delete first 6 numbers from string PHP

Tags: php

This is probably really easy but I didnt really find any concrete solution.

I parsed some data and unfortunately some of the columns from my database is composed of numbers.

There is a maximum of 6 numbers at the beginning. There can be only 2 or 3 or even 5, and after there is the name of my article.

I get something like this :

```
12345 Article1
23 Article2
```

I would be able to check the first 6 characters from my string and delete the numbers only considering there can be numbers after those 6 strings.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could `explode()` on the space with a limit of 2 parts, and then take the second part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
$str = '12345 Article1';
$str = preg_replace('/^\d{1,6}\s/', '', $str);
echo $str;
```

you replace up to 6 chars and a space from the beginning of the string with empty string. You should get the article title only.

In case the string doesn't have the digits and a space at the beginning your string should stay the way it was.

Comment: That was it thanks! I was trying to use preg_replace but thought it required to use something to divide the string before using it. I feel like a idiot... thanks again!

Comment: Just make sure I got your problem right. Basically as long as there are 1 to 6 digits followed by a space they will be removed from the string. The problem is if there are no numbers but the article begins with the digits. They will get removed too.

Comment: There are always digits at the beginning followed by a space and then the name of the article. So your solution is exactly what I needed.